# Find a general formula for $x_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Suppose that the sequence $(x_k)$ is defined by $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 6, x_2 = 1$ and $$x_{k+3} = −x_{k+2}+17x_{k+1}−15x_k\quad \text{for }\, k\geq0.$$ Find a general formula for $x_k$.

I have this answer to this question but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone show me without omitting any steps? Thanks!

Comment: I hope that edit is corresponding. You have `edit` button below question if you want to see what I did.

Comment: @Cortizol Thanks a lot!! It is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U_k=\begin{bmatrix} x_{k+2} \\ x_{k+1} \\ x_k  \end{bmatrix}$

then

$$U_{k+1}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 17 & -15 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &1 &0\end{bmatrix}U_k=AU_k$$
so

$$U_k=A^kU_0$$

characteristic polynomial of $A$
$$\lambda^3+\lambda^2-17\lambda+15$$
has three roots $1,3,-5$,  $A$ is diagonalizable.

so

$$x_n=a+b3^n+c(-5)^n$$

$x_0 = 0, x_1 = 6, x_2 = 1$, so
$$a+b+c=0,a+3b-5c=6,a+9b+25c=1$$